# MySQL JOIN with 3 tables and COUNT() not working

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm having a problem with my MySQL statement. I need a query that counts the number of comments and the number of topics a user has created. My table structure is something like this:

```
Table 'users'
-------------
user_id
user_name
...

Table 'topics'
--------------
topic_id
topic_user_id
...

Table 'topiccomments'
---------------------
topiccomment_id
topiccomment_user_id
...
```

So far I've been able to produce this query:

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_name,
    COUNT(t.topic_user_id) as topic_count,
    COUNT(tc.topiccomment_user_id) as topiccomment_count
FROM 
    users as u
    JOIN topiccomments as tc ON u.user_id = tc.topiccomment_user_id
    JOIN topics as t ON u.user_id = t.topic_user_id
WHERE 
    u.user_id = t.topic_user_id AND
    u.user_id = tc.topiccomment_user_id 
GROUP BY 
    u.user_id
```

This query is executed, but the 'topic_count' and 'topiccomment_count' values are totally wrong and I don't quite understand why.

I was hoping somebody here could help me out?

Comment: It is best to do this as two separate queries. If you really need one query, then create two subqueries.

Comment: I need it in one query because I need to be able to do mysql sorting on the 'topic_count' and 'topiccomment_count' fields...

How would the query with subqueries look like? I have no experience whatsoever with subqueries...

Comment: maybe you can given an example with the data, the wrong and the intended results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change to

```
COUNT(DISTINCT t.topic_id) as topic_count,
COUNT(DISTINCT tc.topiccomment_id) as topiccomment_count
```

This will count the number of distinct topics and topic comments that match the user ID. Before, you were counting the number of rows in the cross-product of topics and topic comments for a given user.

If it works in your situation, I would refactor this into two queries, one for counting topics and one for topic_comments, since this will be more efficient.

Comment: Yes, that's it! The query is working now!

Thank you very much!

gr, bert

Answer (score 2):

quick shot: try replacing count(field) with count(distinct field)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying that quick!

I have tried that too, but then the 'topic_count' and 'topiccomment_count' just return '1', while it should be a higher number...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can delete your entire WHERE clause. It is not necessary because you already took care of it in the JOINs.

To fix your issue, use this in your SELECT clause instead of the current COUNT statements your have:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT t.topic_id) as topic_count,
COUNT(DISTINCT tc.topiccomment_id) as topiccomment_count
```

You are trying to count the number of topics, or topic comments. Not the number of users (which should always be 1).

Comment: Yes, that's it! The query is working now!

Thank you very much!

gr, bert

Answer (score 1):

The JOINs are probably returning a cartesian product of the `topiccomments` and `topics` tables because there is no restriction between their relationship, which could explain why you are getting a high count.

One easy way to tackle this problem is to use correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT  u.user_id, 
        u.user_name,
        SELECT (COUNT(*) FROM topics t WHERE t.id = u.id),
        SELECT (COUNT(*) FROM topiccomments tc WHERE tc.id = u.id)
FROM    users u;
```

You can also use `COUNT(DISTINCT t.topic_id)` and `COUNT(DISTINCT tc.topiccomment_id)` in your original query as some of the other answers suggest. In fact, that may turn out to be more efficient in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be counting the topic and comment ids, not the user_ids of the comment/topic.

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id, 
    u.user_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.topic_id) as topic_count,
    COUNT(DISTINCT tc.topiccomment_id) as topiccomment_count
FROM 
    users as u
    JOIN topiccomments as tc ON u.user_id = tc.topiccomment_user_id
    JOIN topics as t ON u.user_id = t.topic_user_id
GROUP BY 
    u.user_id
```